# error message error: variable '...' has initializer but incomplete type

Tags: c, struct

When compiling my code

```cpp
#include "macro.h"
#ifndef FIT_IT
#define FIT_IT
#endif
#define MAXPOINTS 10000
using namespace std;
double calc_chi2(int iloop, void *params){

struct func_params *part = (struct func_params *)params;
struct fit_data     fd   = part->fd;
...}

int main(int argc, char **argv){
FILE *fp;
size_t size;
int i;
struct func_params part;
setbuf(stdout,NULL);
initialize(argc, argv,&part);
...
}
```

I get the error message:  `error: variable ‘fit_data fd’ has initializer but incomplete type`. The structures are defined in the header 'macro.h':

```cpp
struct func_params
{   
    ...
    struct fit_data{
    char   data_file[100];
    size_t n;
    double nu;
    int    id;
    double lognumin;
    double lognumax;
    double xval[1000];
    double yval[1000];
    double yerr[1000];
          } fd;
     };
```

Does anyone have an idea where it comes from...? I've been searching for hours...

Thanks for your help!

Comment: `using namespace std` is C++, not C.  These are different languages.  Which one are you actually using?

Comment: If you're being taught this is C++ I would suggest you learn C++ from somewhere else.  Besides `using namespace std;` your code is C code.

Comment: To be precise, `using namespace std;` is bad C++, the rest is C.

Comment: Thanks for your comments, the code is from someone else and is written in C but my all program is in C++ and I compile with g++

Answer (score 1):

In this statement there are declared two entities.

```
struct fit_data     fd   = part->fd;
```

The first one is structure `fit_data`  that is not yet defined. And the second one is an object of the structure with name `fd` . The compiler is unable to perform the initialization because it does not know how the structure is defined.

You have to use a qualified name. For example

```
func_params::fit_data     fd   = part->fd;
```

because the structure `fit_data` is declared and defined as an internal member of the structure   `func_params`

Also it is not clear from your code snippets whether fd is defined as a separate global object or you mean a data member of the structure  `struct func_params`. In the last case you have to define an object of the type `struct func_params` and initialize it as an aggregate.

Comment: Okay thanks a lot, but what do you mean by "initializing as an aggregate"? If I'm not wrong, fd is defined as a data member of the structure `struct func_params`

Comment: @ludmi I mean using brace initialization.

Answer (score 1):

As you were said in comment C and C++ are different languages!

The C version is:

```
double calc_chi2(int iloop, void *params){

struct func_params *part = (struct func_params *)params;
struct fit_data     fd   = part->fd;
...}
```

because there is no nesting of types in C, so it compiles fine as C but chokes as C++.

But the C++ version is:

```
double calc_chi2(int iloop, void *params){

struct func_params *part = (struct func_params *)params;
struct funt_params::fit_data     fd   = part->fd;
...}
```

because C++ being an OO language has the notion of type qualification. But this one will be rejected by a C compiler...

TL/DR: even if C++ actually derives from C and if they share common elements, and if the C standard library is included in C++ standard library, which allows some trivial C program to also be C++ correct programs, **C and C++ are different languages**.

Comment: I didn't know that... Indeed it's working now, thanks a lot!